# Spring Boot Could not find acceptable representation for XML responses

Tags: xml, http, spring-boot, jackson, jaxb

I found multiple solutions for this exception and causes but none worked and it seems illogical.

I have REST service class as the following

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import java.util.Map;
@RestController
public class UserRestService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Map> login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> name) {
        ResponseEntity<Map> res = null;
        name.values().forEach(System.out::println);
        return new ResponseEntity<Map>(name, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

As you see, I try to create a POST request with request body as JSON and response as XML, printing the request in the process. It's just simple example but while the request is printed correctly which means it's been received and marshaled to Map. However the response status is 406 (not acceptable)

Exception in the log is

```
John
30
null
2018-08-16 14:05:48.440  WARN 22820 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2018-08-16 14:05:48.481  WARN 22820 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

the Request Header simply has

```
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/json
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.cms</groupId>
    <artifactId>business</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Noting that adding the following dependency solves the problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Request Body `{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }`

Response if `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` is used for `produces` attribute of `@RequestMapping` is `{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }`

Response if `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE` is used for `produces` attribute of `@RequestMapping` & `jackson-dataformat-xml` used is

```
<Map>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <car/>
</Map>
```

Why using JAXB fails in this ?

#### **Update 01**

OK as @Simon comment, I created a sample object (class) to get as request and response with it. **Same exact effect**. Here is the updated code

```
public class MockupResponse {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String car;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(String car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

@Override
public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if (null != name)
            sb.append("Name: " + name + "\n");
        if (null != age)
            sb.append("Age: " + age + "\n");
        if (null != car)
            sb.append("Car: " + car + "\n");

        return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<MockupResponse> login(@RequestBody MockupResponse sample) {
        System.out.println(sample);

        return new ResponseEntity<MockupResponse>(sample, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Because JAXB converts objects to XML and not maps. Why don't you create a class instead of using a map?

Comment: Thank you kindly @SimonMartinelli I was looking for explanation and might create an object later but as you see this is just an example code. I take it that `jackson-dataformat-xml` has the ability to convert maps as an advantage over JAXB right ?

Comment: Sadly, updated the code with object instead of map with exact same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add @XmlRootElement to the class that must be serialized by JAXB like

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MockupResponse {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String car;
...
}
```

Then the XML serialization works.

Read more about that in the Spring Doc:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html

If you use Java 9 and later you must add JAXB and javax.activation to the dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I get same response but with exception thrown `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler`

Comment: you must add javax.activation. See the updated answer

Comment: Damn this dependency is from 2009 and removed from JDK 9/10 as well as jaxb. Should paid attention to this. Thanks for the help @SimonMartinelli really appreciated

Comment: Happy that it works. The whole JAXB and activation was a stupid idea to remove because a lot of frameworks are still using that.